# Laravel - Trigger queue on form and update db after set time

Tags: php, laravel

I've been looking through Laravel's queue and schedulers and I'm not sure if it's what I need to do what I want. I'll try explain simply.

First, I hit a submit (basic form) that creates a db row with say a number and a created_at and finished_at. JS then creates a timer on the page that counts down (math) from the created at to the finished time.

I can do all that fine, what I'm struggling to get my head around is how do I make this then change that number value of 0 to 1 say after 10 minutes, or whatever time I wanted to specify? I'm not sure how to go about this. This sort of stuff is new to me.

Any help/pointing me in the right direction would be great! Explanations too. :)

Edit: To add, I looked at things like socket.io but I'm not sure if that's what I want too and if I can even use that with laravel as it's a framework off of node.js

Answer (score 0):

Is the backend actually doing any work besides storage? If not I would skip the complexity of trying to open a web socket to tell the frontend the task is finished.

If all you're trying to accomplish is display something on the frontend to the user after an interval of time I would just use JS 100%.

However if the backend does need to do work and trigger the display change on the frontend you will need to open up a web socket.

Your constraint on Laravel's scheduling is that they are run at predefined times. So if these actions are triggered by the user and not a set time, skip using the scheduler. Instead use Events to broadcast something to node.

Comment: Yeah that what I was thinking was the problem with scheduling. I need it so when I press a button somewhere in the back end its saved something like a job and in 10 minutes will trigger a method or something from a controller. Not sure how I go about it. The frontend JS side is fine. Edit: when I say in 10 minutes I don't just want a job to run every time minutes. Rather a job is created when I press the button. So I could press the button 5 times every 10 seconds, creating 5 different jobs that finish 10 seconds apart from each other.